# Log4j2 Rolling appender - fileName "sliding" according to pattern

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am looking for rollover strategy where current log (*active output target* in [manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#DefaultRolloverStrategy)'s terminology) file name is not fixed but specified by a pattern, or - more precisely - same pattern as in `filePattern` attribute.

I want to achieve daily rollover where today's log is, say, `log-2015-05-05.log` and on midnight framework just stops writing it and starts writing into `log-2015-05-06.log`. However, AFAIK, current configuration allows only

```
<RollingFile name="ROLFILE"
    fileName="log.log"
    filePattern="log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
>
```

Specifying same value into `fileName` attribute doesn't work (leads to file with sensitive characters literally interpreted). I noticed no example or SO question with such a dynamic value of `fileName`. Note the `fileName="log-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"` doesn't solve problem since expression is evaluated only at startup and events are still sent into file even if their timestamp doesn't match the expression.

I am migrating from Log4j 1.2 to Log4j 2.2. In old version, required behavior was possible using

```
<appender name="ROLFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern" value="log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    ...
```

I prefer to preserve current way since some log analyzing tools rely on it.
Is it possible in Log4j2?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if this works, but you can try using a double `$$` in the date lookup. This allows the variable to be resolved at runtime.

```
<RollingFile name="ROLFILE"
    fileName="log-$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
    filePattern="oldlog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
>
```

You may need to be careful to ensure that the *active output target* file name is different from the after-rollover file name. (I used 'oldlog' in the snippet above.)

Comment: Thanks Remko, unfortunately, it doesn't work. The framework creates file with name `log-${date`. I have explored internals of `rolling` package and found what I treat as root cause of problem: the `RollingFileManager` is tightly bound to one file which cannot be changed. I made little bit hacked `RolloverStrategy` which solves my problem, I will post it as separate answer.

Comment: Oh that is too bad. Perhaps raise a feature request on the log4j2 Jira issue tracker? (Or vote for an existing issue if this request already exists.)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I wrote [my own rollover strategy](https://gist.github.com/tomaszalusky/b9109c0faddafe099835) which generates different set of rollover actions. Instead renaming active file the active file name is simply replaced inside `RollingFileManager`. Yes, it's ugly reflection hack and also appender must be initialized with `fileName` constant corresponding with current date and having same pattern, e.g.

```
<RollingFile name="ROLFILE"
    fileName="log-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
    filePattern="log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
>
    <SlidingFilenameRolloverStrategy />
    ...
```

yet for me this solution is worth doing it despite these small drawbacks.
(Initial `fileName` stays forever as a key in `AbstractManager` registry `MAP` even if in manager itself it has been changed - seems it doesn't mind, I also tried replacing manager in registry for new one but it's impossible to collect all parameters necessary for its construction.)

I hope this hack shouldn't have been so ugly if `RollingFileManager` API made it possible normal way. I got some hope seeing [this javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RolloverDescription.html#getActiveFileName%28%29) but framework AFAIK never utilizes this field, let alone for mutating `RollingFileAppender`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work just fine using:

```
 fileName="log-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
 filePattern="log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
```

I use it with log4j2 version 2.5

Comment: This didn't work for me in log4j 2.6.  The pattern is resolved only once during startup, so after the first rollover the main/current logfile has a stale name.  However, [seems like they've finally implemented this in 2.8](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-907)

Answer (score -1):

This has been implemented in **Log4j 2.8** (see [issue LOG4J2-1101](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1101)).

Currently it only works with a `RollingFile` appender by omitting the `filename` parameter and using a `DirectWriteRolloverStrategy`.

Also, this feature seems to have some issues with the `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy` (the first rollover doesn't happen so every logfile is offset by one interval); `CronTriggeringPolicy` works properly.

Example config:

```
<RollingRandomAccessFile name="MyLogger"
    filePattern="logs/application.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    <Policies>
        <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 * * * * ?" evaluateOnStartup="true"/>
    </Policies>
    <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy/>
</RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

Support for `RollingRandomAccessFile` appender is requested in [issue LOG4J2-1878](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1878).

***Edit:*** Changed to CronTriggeringPolicy policy after finding TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy had issues.

Comment: @lucasvc the config you posted is using a SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy instead of a CronTriggeringPolicy, which seems to be the only policy working properly in this scenario.

Comment: I think the schedule in the CronTriggeringPolicy should have '**schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"**' to roll at midnight.  According to Cron Expression Descriptor, ["0 * * * * ?"](https://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/?expression=0+*+*+*+*+%3F&locale=en) evaluates to Every minute, while ["0 0 0 * * ?"](https://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/?expression=0+0+0+*+*+%3F&locale=en) evaluates to At 12:00 AM.  I'm not saying you'll get a new log every minute, but the expression will be evaluated every minute which is probably overkill.